# How to create different menu for non admin user using PHP session?

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-2

I'm new in this forum, recently I just created web application to manage stock and so on. (sorry for my bad English)

I'm just considering if I have to make different menu for non admin user. This is menu for admin

[this is admin menu](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5eDAe-rMMasWEhjVjRDQ21OdFk)

I need to remove master and setting menu for registered user.
can I make it just by using session?

Comment: stackoverflow is not a forum. And we can see that you are new by your reputation and your user page.

Comment: [Stack Overflow isn't a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum) - please see [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before posting.

Comment: oh sorry, i know this isn't forum i mean it's like community where you can share or asking about something

Answer (score 1):

Allowing different people to do different things is done by asking the *authorization* component. CodeIgniter does not have it's own authorization component. You have to look somewhere else for one.

Sessions won't help directly. The session knows which user is using the application; that information must be passed to the authorization component to determine whether the user is allowed to access pages that are reserved for administrators.

Comment: i know, that's the problem :/

Comment: *Knowing* is not the problem. What hinders you in finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the session before displaying menu in a template

Ex

```
$this->c_type = $this->CI->session->userdata('logtype');


        $menubar ='';

        if($this->c_type == 'Admin')
        {
           $menubar = $this->CI->load->view('admin/menubar', $data, true);      

        }                   
        else
                {
                    $menubar = $this->CI->load->view('general/menubar', $data, true);
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user_id by following

```
    $user_id=$this->session->userdata('user_id');

if($user_id ==1){ // I considered admin user_id =1
 echo "admin menu";
}
else{
 echo "user menu";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my main.php code

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
         redirect(site_url('login').'?u='.uri_string(), 'refresh');
    }
    $this->data['title'] = 'Home';
    $this->data['active'] = 'home';
    $this->data['menu'] = array('home','keuangan','penjualan','pembelian','stok','master','setting');
}

function index()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Main';
    $this->load->view('common/header',$this->data);
    $this->load->view('common/footer');
}
```

}